# How to create an element with information put in the form after being submitted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create this small app that would be something like a typical contact list with phone numbers and names of people. Essentially, I want all the information I put in the form (First Name, Phone Number etc) to be displayed below the List of Phone Numbers, but I'm having issues writing a working function in JavaScript.

```
const form = document.querySelector('#phone-form');
const list = document.querySelector('.phone-list');
const inputPhone = document.querySelector('#addPhone');
const inputFirstName = document.querySelector('#addPhone');
const inputLastName = document.querySelector('#addPhone');

function loadEventListener(){
form.addEventListener('submit', addPhone);
}

function addPhone(e){
if(inputPhone.value === ' ' &&
   inputFirstName === ' ' &&
   inputLastname === ' ') {
       alert('Missing information');
   }

const li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputPhone.value));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputFirstName.value));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputLastName.value));

list.appendChild(li);

e.preventDefault();
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
 <form id="phone-form">
 <label>Phone Number</label>
 <input placeholder="Enter phone number" id="phone-number"></input>
 <label>First Name</label>
 <input placeholder="First Name" id="first-name"></input>
 <label>Last Name</label>
 <input placeholder="Enter last name" id="last-name"></input>
 <button type="submit" id="addPhone">Add Phone</button>
```

```
<h1>List of Phone Numbers</h1> 
   <ul class="phone-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Where is your list '.phone-list'?

Answer (score 0):

In your `querySelector`s at the top, you have the incorrect ids being selected. They do not match up with your HTML ids.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#phone-form');
const list = document.querySelector('.phone-list');
const inputPhone = document.querySelector('#phone-number');
const inputFirstName = document.querySelector('#first-name');
const inputLastName = document.querySelector('#last-name');
console.log(inputPhone);

form.addEventListener('submit', addPhone, false);

function addPhone(e){
e.preventDefault();

if(inputPhone.value === ' ' &&
   inputFirstName === ' ' &&
   inputLastname === ' ') {
       alert('Missing information');
   }

let li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputPhone.value));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputFirstName.value));
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(inputLastName.value));

list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<form id="phone-form">
 <label>Phone Number</label>
 <input placeholder="Enter phone number" id="phone-number"></input>
 <label>First Name</label>
 <input placeholder="First Name" id="first-name"></input>
 <label>Last Name</label>
 <input placeholder="Enter last name" id="last-name"></input>
 <button type="submit" id="addPhone">Add Phone</button>
 </form>
 
 <ul class="phone-list">
 <li>first</li>
 </ul>
```